# Filter and then Save

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I have a two forms: "Cover" and "Form_1".
I have two comboboxes in "COVER". One contains a list of years and the second contains a list of names. The first one is of type Number and the second one is Text.

On the "Cover" there is a button which takes takes you to "Form_1" upon a button click.
"Form_1" contains the same two dropdown menus from "COVER" and it stores the exact values chosen from "CoveR".

The problem:
The problem is that it should be able to filter out specific data upon choosing specific values from the dropdown menus and then save. But it saves the chosen values from the dropmenu first and then filters out the data. So, the same data appears for 2011 and 2012.

It should be able to filter about the specific data first and then save.
Is there any way of doing this? for example, creating a "save" button so that it only saves upon a button click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i figured out the solution:

Just link the fields to the comboboxes on click.

stLinkCriteria = "[Program_Name]='" & Me![Combo2] & "' AND [BudgetYear]=" & Me![Combo0]